# Multiplying 1 million

Tags: c++, long-integer

Why when you do this:

```
int a = 1000000 , b = 1000000;
long long product = a * b;
cout<<product;
```

It gives some random trash value?Why do both a and b need to be long long in order to calculate it?

Comment: Because int cannot store the product of multiplication. Check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-data-types/ data type sizes for more info. Int can hold a max value of 2147483647

Comment: An `int` has a limited number of bits and you overflow a signed integer and introduce undefined behavior in your program. The trash value could just as well had been "smurf". Check [fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Comment: int op int gives int. One of the two has to be long long in order to have the other promoted to long long.

Comment: The value is not random, but modulus 2 ^ 32

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's UB in C++ - even in C++20 where two's complement is standard.

Comment: Interesting fun fact about `int`. There is no defined maximum. `int` is at least 16 bits and no larger than `long`. So if `long` is 4096 bits, the maximum size of `int` could be from 32K to Zounds...

Comment: Indeed. But on most computers I have access to, it gives aritmetic modulus 2^32. Can you name a computer which don't give that? I won't say "trash random" for the result

Comment: please include the output in the question. UB or not it is unlikely just "random trash"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, I can't - but the standard committee [revised the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html) about making it defined in C++20 and decided not to.

Comment: So practically speaking, the result is very well reproducible.... So "random" is bad wording

Comment: Reality... Always getting in the way of having a good time.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Indeed! :)  - but UB is UB ...

Comment: thank you all but i am still a newbie programmer...Of course i didn't know it is modulus 2^32 or anything :)

Comment: (1/2) Had an answer to your most recent question, but you deleted it.

Let v be the last node to be finished. Every node that can reach v in the original graph (hence that v can reach in the transpose) is in v's strong component. Why? Suppose to the contrary that x is a node that can reach v, but v can't reach x.

Comment: (2/2) When we start x, the node v cannot be on the stack at the time because that would imply a path to x. We can't finish x until we've at least started every node that x can reach, so if v starts before x, it's already finished (because not on the stack), and if v starts after x, it finishes before x (because it's higher on the stack than x). Contradiction.

This argument extends to a correctness proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are observing the effects of [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). This:

```
a * b
```

is an (arithmetic) expression of type `int`, as both operands `a` and `b` are of type `int`. Trying to store the value of 1000000000000 into an `int` results in the so-called *signed integer overflow* which is undefined behavior.

Either cast one of the operands to `long long`, thus causing the entire expression [to become](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) `long long`, which is sufficiently large to accept the value of 1000000000000:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 1000000, b = 1000000;
    auto product = static_cast<long long>(a) * b;
    std::cout << product;
}
```

Or define one of the operands as `long long`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long a = 1000000;
    int b = 1000000;
    auto product = a * b;
    std::cout << product;
}
```

Optionally, use `unsigned long` instead.

Comment: Oh , so when you multiply two integers , the value will be as well stored inside an integer?

Comment: @cosmin-andreiparaschiv [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)  - Check the _promotion_ parts.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine. When you do multiplication of `int` and `int` if it gets out of limit then to put it in a long long variable you multiply the result with `1ll` or `1LL`. When you multiply the result with `1ll` the result is converted to long long during calculation of product itself.

```
int a = 1000000 , b = 1000000;
    
long long product = 1ll * a * b;
    
cout << product;
```

Comment: Casting at least one of the `int`s to a `long long` would work as well, assuming we don't have 16 bit `int` bunging thing up right at the beginning.

Comment: Note that multiplying by `1ll` isn't a cast. An actual cast would be using `static_cast<long long>(a)` or a C-style `(long long) a`